# Completely clueless on computer science assignments

Tags: c++

This question isn't very technical, but I'm in desperate need of help and I thought this would be the best place to post this question. I'm in an computer science course, data structures and algorithms and we have dealt mainly with singly / doubly linked lists as our main data structure, skip lists and time complexity. Now the problem is, I'm failing this course badly. I go to every lecture, lab and pay attention, but completely clueless on the assignments that are given.

My question is what do I do when I'm completely clueless on an assignment and I don't know where to start, for example implementing a doubly linked list with assignment operators & copy constructors? I have no plan on dropping this course or dropping out of this program, but any other advice will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Visit office hours and ask the professor/TA. It's basically their job. Also, "doubly linked list with assignment operators" means that you need to know "doubly linked list" and "assignment operators". If you understand them, then it should be simple to combine them. The fact that you can't do this means that you likely don't really understand one of them (which is not surprising, given that for labs it's often sufficient to almost copy-paste code from lectures). So read about them, and implement simpler versions in simpler contexts, on your own (without looking at any external code).

Comment: Moreover, if you live in a country / study at an institution which has study fees, you are literally paying someone to help you with this problem, and not going to them means you are wasting your money.

Comment: http://cseducators.stackexchange.com